# How can I generate random data with different varience (heteroskedasticity). in R

Tags: r

[image]

The regression model should be like the one on the left, and its value should be distributed normally like the equation on the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `rnorm()` function support vector entry. Hence, you can generate u_i given x_i using the following line

```
    x <- c(1:10)
    u <- rnorm(rep(1,10), mean = rep(0,10), sd = sqrt(0.5*sqrt(x)))
```

Then

```
    y <- 10 + x + u
```

To validation:

```
set.seed(2021)
validation.u <- NULL
for (i in 1:1000){
  u_i <- rnorm(rep(1,10), mean = rep(0,10), sd = 0.5*sqrt(x))
  validation.u <- rbind(validation.u, u_i)
}


colMeans(validation.u)
> [1]  0.04053143  0.02626776 -0.01915211  0.02319424  0.05187192 -0.06950472  0.01335739  0.03787621  0.01348861  0.03323902
diag(cov(validation.u))
> [1] 0.5277132 0.6585050 0.8586679 1.1081190 1.1200815 1.2266432 1.2553346 1.4172857 1.5748265 1.6788966
```

Comment: why mean = rep(0,10) ? I want mean = 0 .

Comment: I changed some codes.
`x <- c(1:5) 
u <- rnorm(rep(1,10), mean = 0, sd = sqrt(0.5*sqrt(x)))
y <- 10 + 20*x + u
set.seed(26)
validation.u <- NULL
for (i in 1:20){
  u_i <- rnorm(rep(1,5), mean =0 , sd = 0.5*sqrt(x))
  validation.u <- rbind(validation.u, u_i)
}
View(validation.u)`

Comment: Here 10 is the dimension of x. We use mean = rep(0,10) is just to keep consistent with the dimension in the "sd" argument. Note that rep(0,10) still ensure mean = 0 and that sqrt(x) here is of 10-dimension. It is very dangerous to have different dimensions in these two arguments. It might lead to misleading results.

Comment: Your new code is problematic because your x here is 5-dimensional. But you used rep(1,10) in rnorm in the first line, which is of 10 dimensions. You need to change it into rep(1,5) instead, like the later one.